# How to determine whether a modal popup is Open or Close in asp.net using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

I am Opening and Closing Modal Popup in my Asp.net project using jquery like this

```
$find("MyPopup").show(); // To Open my popup
$find("MyPopup").hide(); // To cloe my popup
```

But, I want to perform some action, when my popup has open like this

```
if(MyPopup is Open){
    alert("Open");
}
else{
    alert("Close");
}
```

How Can I do this

Comment: What is MyPopup? in $find("MyPopup").show(); ? Is it id, class or tag?

Comment: you can check the display value on id/class or you can check whether the element is visible or not .Eg:- `$('idOrClassOfPopup').is(':visible')`

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be achived by using visibilityChanged.js plugin.

Source: https://github.com/shaunbowe/jquery.visibilityChanged

```js
$("#tester").visibilityChanged({
    callback: function(element, visible) {
       // do something here
    },
    runOnLoad: false,
    frequency: 100
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunbowe/kb24kqfx/4/

Otherwise your using "MutationObserver"
Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```js
$(function() {
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $('#mydiv').show();
  });

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    alert('Attributes changed!');
  });
  var target = document.querySelector('#mydiv');
  observer.observe(target, {
    attributes: true
  });

});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">hidden</div>
<button id="show">Show and hidden div</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :visible

```
if($find("MyPopup").is(":visible")){
    alert("Open");
}
else{
    alert("Close");
}
```

Comment: I would put it after the $find("MyPopup").show(); statement.